# How to redirecting homepage in AEM

Tags: aem

Like title suggests, when I open the level 1 of the site structure (ex. DummySite), I want it to redirect to the level 2 (ex. EN). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are looking for is a Sling redirect.

```
/content/dummy-site
    jcr:content
       @sling:redirect - true
       @sling:resourceType - foundation/components/redirect
       @redirectTarget - /content/dummy-site/en
```